# What do locants with prime symbols (e.g. 4’) mean?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I was reading an article about acetaminophen and it says its chemical name is 4'-hydroxyacetanilide.

What does the 4 signify and most importantly, what does the apostrophe mean? First semester chem student so if you can answer in layman terms that would be great.

Comment: 4: fourth atom (usually but not necessarily carbon). Prime (not apostrophe): concerning the secondary structure not the primary one. Should be explained in every organic chemistry textbook in the nomenclature section.

Comment: @Jan What do you mean by secondary and primary structure? Thanks

Comment: It’s a bit hard to explain concisely. In your example, you have an amide (acetanilide). The carbonyl side will be referred to with only the numbers (e.g. 2-hydroxyacetanilide) while the amino side’s carbons are referenced with primed numbers (4'-hydroxy). Another example would be 4,4'-dimethylbisphenyl; here, an arbitrary phenyl group is the primary and the other arbitrary one is the secondary.

Comment: See also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61155/what-does-the-prime-symbol-mean-in-organic-nomenclature-e-g-2

Answer (score 4):

4 means the fourth atom and the prime symbol specifies the part of the molecule (one ' means the secondary structure), so 4'-hydroxyacetanilide means you have acetanilide with a hydroxide group on the fourth atom of the secondary structure.
Naming organic compounds works like this:

> 1. Find the longest continueous chain of carbon atoms. Called the parent chain this chain establishes the base alkane name for the compound.
> 2. Number the carbon atoms in the parent chain beginning with the end closest to any substituents.
> 3. Using the correct substituent name (methyl, ethyl, chloro,etc.), and the carbon atom number on the parent chain.
> 4. If a particular substituent occurs more than once, use a prefix (di-, tri-, tetra-) to indicate the number of those substituents.
> 5. List the alkyl substituents in alphabetical order.

Source: http://intro.chem.okstate.edu/1014/lecture/organic.html

Here are the IUPAC guidelines about the nomenclature of organic compounds:
http://old.iupac.org/reports/provisional/abstract04/BB-prs310305/Chapter1.pdf

Comment: thank you ! What exactly do you mean by secondary and primary structure? Also, when you say 4th atom, how do you tell what the 4th atom is?

Comment: @user54747 The quote should explain how to find the fourth atom. As for the secondary structure...To be honest I don't know it myself as I only added information given in a comment.

Comment: Assume you have a biphenyl (Google it) with a bromine in the 3-position (aka, meta) in one ring and a chlorine at the 4-position  (aka, para) in the other, its name is 3-bromo-4'-chloro-1,1'-biphenyl. The primary structure is the one without primes; the secondary with primes. The 1,1' nomenclature is the point of attachment of the two benzene rings.